# BUG navigating from a view to another in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, toolbar, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a problem and I really don't know how can i fix this. When I'm pressing the button, I want to navigate to the next view, but at the last view, it didn't work and it pushes me out to the MainView. So, in the CartView, if the onboardingState == 1, it will create an Order and the status will be changed to "pending", and will show the WaitingOrderView(), but is not working as expected.

I will put a view under the code that I will share right know.

```
struct CartView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
        @State var onboardingState: Int = 0
        @State var index = 0
        @State private var timer: AnyCancellable?

        var body: some View {
                ZStack {
                    switch onboardingState {
                    case 0 :
                        VStack {
                        welcomeSection
                        Spacer()
                        bottomButton
                            .padding(30)
                        }
                    case 1 :
                        VStack {
                        welcomeSection2
                        Spacer()
                        bottomButton
                            .padding(30)
                        }

                    case 2 :
                        VStack {
                        detailOrder
                        Spacer()
                        bottomButton
                            .padding(30)
                        }
                    default:
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    extension CartView {
        private var bottomButton : some View {
            Text("Continue")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.onboardingColor)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .onTapGesture {
                    handleNextButtonPressed()
                }
        }

        private var welcomeSection: some View {

            PaymentView()
        }

        private var welcomeSection2: some View {

            LivrareView()
        }
        @ViewBuilder
        private var detailOrder: some View {
            ZStack {
                if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                    status.key == StatusKey.pending.rawValue
                })?.id
                {
                    WaitingOrderView()
                }
                else
                {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    extension CartView {
        func handleNextButtonPressed() {
            if onboardingState == 1 {
                syncViewModel.createOrder()
                onboardingState += 1
            }
            else {
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    onboardingState += 1
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    private var menus : FetchedResults<LocalMenu>

    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            NavigationView{

             MeniuriView()
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            ToolbarButtons(numberOfProducts: menus.count)
                    }
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                            Text(Texts.mainViewText1)
                                .font(.system(size: 24))
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .padding()
                        }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text(Texts.mainViewText2)
                Image(systemName: "fork.knife")
            }
            NavigationView {
                AlteleView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text(Texts.mainViewText3)
                Image("altele", bundle: Bundle.main)
            }
        }
        .accentColor(Color.tabItemColor)
    }
}
```

```
struct ToolbarButtons: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
    private var cartOrder : FetchedResults<CartOrders>
    var numberOfProducts : Int

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Spacer()
            if syncViewModel._order.status == 0 && syncViewModel._order.id == 0{
                NavigationLink(destination: CartView()
                                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Text(Texts.cartText)
                            .font(.system(size: 24))
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                               , label: {
                    Image("otherIcon")
                        .padding(.top, 5)
                }
                )
            }
            else  if syncViewModel._order.id == cartOrder.first?.id  ?? Int32(syncViewModel._order.id) {
                NavigationLink  {
                    WaitingOrderView()
                } label: {
                    ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                        Image("cartIcon")
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                        if numberOfProducts > 0 {
                            Text("\(numberOfProducts)")
                                .font(.caption2).bold()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                                .background(Color.tabItemColor)
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .offset(x: 10, y: -8)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct WaitingOrderView {
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    let transition: AnyTransition = .asymmetric(
        insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
        removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                status.key == StatusKey.pending.rawValue
            })?.id {
                ChefView()
                    .environmentObject(syncViewModel)
            }
           else  if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                status.key == StatusKey.accepted.rawValue
            })?.id
            {
                OrderConfirmedView()
            }
            else if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                status.key == StatusKey.readyForDelivery.rawValue
            })?.id {
                OrderReadyForDeliveryView()
            }
            else if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                status.key == StatusKey.onTheWay.rawValue
            })?.id {
                OrderOnTheWayView()
            } else if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                status.key == StatusKey.completed.rawValue
            })?.id {
                OrderCompletedView()
            } else if syncViewModel._order.status == syncViewModel.statusList.first(where: { status in
                status.key == StatusKey.canceled.rawValue
            })?.id {
                OrderCanceledView()
            }
        }
      
     
    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is a long shot, but I often find that adding `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to the `NavigationView` fixes the problem 
of navigation going back to the "MainView".

Comment: @workingdog tried it right now, is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

These might not be the reason for the exact bug but your use of SwiftUI is non-standard and will likely cause you problems. In browsing your code here is a list of issues I noticed:

1. We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, we use `@State` and we can use a custom struct to make some logic more testable and the whole reason is to take advantage of Swift's value semantics - see [Managing User Interface State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state). If you use objects instead of value types you will have major problems. Also worth watching [Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/) the first half is about view state and shows the use of custom structs, e.g. `struct EditorConfig`.
2. You are using computed vars e.g. `private var detailOrder: some View` instead of custom Views, e.g. `DetailOrderView`. This breaks SwiftUI's dependency tracking. You are supposed to break up your hierarchy into small views with only a few lets or states so `body` will be recomputed less often, which is called having tighter invalidation. A `DetailOrderView` could have let orderStatus so although it might be init many times, its body is only computed when orderStatus is different. In your current code your entire massive `body` is recomputed when `orderStatus` changes.
3. `var numberOfProducts : Int` should be let.
4. We try not to use `if` inside body which compiles to a `_ConditionalView` and breaks SwiftUI's structural identity. [See Demystify SwiftUI WWDC 2021](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/). You can avoid this with something like `Text(orderStatus.complete ? "Complete" : "In-progress")` so there is always a Text just with different params. We can also use modifiers conditionally by using the usual `.automatic` param in the else case.